# Unable to remove Google Account from Sync

Tags: sync

I want to remove Google account from AutoSync since I want to use Outlook.com for syncing of my contacts, calendar, email etc. I am able to sync Outlook.com, but unable to remove Google Account from automatically syncing. There is no disable sync button for google Account.

I use a Redmi 1S mobile, on MIUI.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'll keep looking but all I can think are: Factory reset and don't log in to Google Account (pretty nuclear option) OR you could go to `Settings> Accounts and synch > Your Google Account > Untick EVERY option one by one`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any untick option for Google Account -> options....

Comment: Options, Accounts, google, then click on your email address with the synch icon beside it, then untick EVERYTHING. It depends on how the menus work in MiUi though, I haven't used it in about 3 years.

Comment: As i was saying, I couldn't find any way to uncheck/check. I can only see "Touch to Sync now"

Comment: I presume you tried long pressing them and so on to see if they do anything. I have no idea, I have never seen that, it seems MiUi has it's own way of doing it. Maybe ask MiUi. I can't help but maybe someone with the ROM will know. Actually it seems like you can't and you'll have to go to Contacts and unsynch, the email and unsynch and so on for every single thing, up to uninstalling some apps like Google Plus. I hope that's wrong.

Comment: When i go to contacts->account, its taking me to the main sync settings. Looks like I can't unselect google account, or for that matter any added account, from unsyncing. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Auto Sync should be enabled for checkboxes to appear. Without Auto Sync on, the checkboxes didn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

When you add google account at that time you will get option for auto sync. You can remove account and add account again.

On android 10 on my mobile, setting / google/ backup and auto sync.